Activating an environment in Vscode
I have a script to activate my environment using source env.sh. In order for VSCode to inherit this environment I need to launch code from the same shell after sourcing the environment.
But what can I do when I need to do this on a remote machine? I connect VSCode to my remote ssh but it does not source env (I cannot add it to my bashrc) sourcing it from the integrated terminal does not help.
I tried sourcing in the integrated terminal. I understand that VSCode sources bashrc but I cannot do that.
